# MYSQL/Exact Target query does not pass validation

Tags: mysql, exacttarget

Exact Target uses MYSQL, however it prevents me from using SOME commands. either wait, I get this error
"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

```html
select tm.CustomerID as customerid, tp.Category1 as product_category, (SELECT RIGHT(tod.ProductCode,2)) as size, (SELECT count ((SELECT RIGHT(tod.ProductCode,2)))  as unique_size_purchases FROM ent.customer_product_sizing_profile
 GROUP by customerid)
from ENT.TAR_POS_CUSTOMER as tm
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENT.TAR_POS_ORDER_HEADER as th
ON tm.CustomerID=th.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENT.TAR_POS_ORDER_DETAILS as tod
ON tod.OrderNumber=th.OrderNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENT.TAR_POS_PRODUCT as tp
ON tp.ProductCode=tod.ProductCode
```

Comment: ExactTarget does not use MySQL, it uses SQL Server.

Comment: You should post ET questions in the Salesforce section -- [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com)  -- and tag ET specific questions with `marketing-cloud`